# is graphql executing mongoose queries automatically?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

If i return a query from a graphql resolver like so:

`someResolver = () => SomeModel.find()`

it just works and responds with a database result.

How is this happening ? Why don't i have to call `.exec()` on it for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `Model.find()` return a `Query`, but it's a `PromiseLike` type.

Here is the doc: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#built-in-promises

And, in `graphql` `resolver`, you can return a `promise` or use `async/await` or just return a constant value

https://graphql.org/learn/execution/#asynchronous-resolvers

> During execution, GraphQL will wait for Promises, Futures, and Tasks to complete before continuing and will do so with optimal concurrency.

`Model.find().exec()` return a fully-fledged promise, it works fine too.

Comment: Great. Thanks! But is there some recomended approach? For example to choose .exec() over constant value or .find() or it doesnt matter ? Can it have any influence on the performance or anything ?

Comment: I think if it has performance issue. It's `mongoose` issue about `.find()` and `.exec()` and how times your resolver execute. That's another problem. You can take a look about https://github.com/facebook/dataloader